# How do I append all the rows in my pandas dataframe into one big row?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I want to create new columns based on the time column.
I am trying to append the last 5 values in each row onto row zero, and then use the time column as the header for each column.

index ticker date   time    vol open    close   high    low

0   AAPL 2022-01-06 09:00   121611 174.78   174.00  175.08  173.76
1   AAPL 2022-01-06 10:00   83471   174.11  173.89  174.64  173.88
2   AAPL 2022-01-06 11:00   76327   173.99  173.55  174.25  173.16
3   AAPL 2022-01-06 12:00   83471   174.11  173.89  174.64  173.88

Ultimately I want it to look like this:

Ticker date time    vol9am open9am close9am high9am low9am vol10am open10am close10am high10am low10am

AAPL 2022-01-06 09:00   121611 174.78   174.00  175.08  173.76  83471   174.11  173.89  174.64  173.88

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas' `unstack` function will achieve this. This will provide a multi-index for the column names; you can use `to_flat_index` if you only want a single layer index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['index', 'ticker', 'date', 'time', 'vol', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low'], 
            data = [
                [0, 'AAPL', '2022-01-06', '09:00', 121611, 174.78, 174.00, 175.08, 173.76],
                [1, 'AAPL', '2022-01-06', '10:00', 83471, 174.11, 173.89, 174.64, 173.88],
                [2, 'AAPL', '2022-01-06', '11:00', 76327, 173.99, 173.55, 174.25, 173.16],
                [3, 'AAPL', '2022-01-06', '12:00', 83471, 174.11, 173.89, 174.64, 173.88],
            ]
            )

df.set_index(['ticker','date','time'])[['open','close']].unstack()
```

Ideally if you can post your questions with some minimum working code it makes it much easier to replicate :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. My code merely generates a dataframe from an API pull, that's why I didn't post it.  Your code works nicely.  now I just add "data = df.values.tolist()" to pass through any number of time-based list to create one mega row. Thanks again @DaveB.

Comment: No worries - feel free to accept the answer (the green tick) if it helped :)